Reset Functions for Reinforcement Learning in Matlab
So im attempting to build a Reinforcement Learning AI in Matlab to train a controller for a system. The issue I'm running into is with the reset function that allows some of the initial parameters of the simulation to be randomised. Im using a live script to set up paramters and a Simulink model to run the Agent and the Environment.
Im trying to randomise two values: the start time of the simulation and the length for which it needs to run. However im having difficult getting anything to work so ive just been focusing on the latter for now.
What i have is:
ChargeDue = Simulink.SimulationInput("Reinforcment_learning");
%Reinforment_learning is the name of the model

env = rlSimulinkEnc(......

env.ResetFcn = @(ChargeDue)LocalRestFcn(ChargeDue);

This should call the reset funtion which is a separate function file with:
function [ChargeDue] = LocalRestFcn(ChargeDue)

cd = (randi(3)*13 + rand*3)*60*60;
ChargeDue.SetVariables = cd;

end

I get the error message: "There was an error evaluating the reset function"
I suspect i've done most of this wrong.
